# SaveFileDialog doesn't add extension to filename if ShowHelp = true and filename contains "." [.NET]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog

If we set flag **ShowHelp= true** of SaveFileDialog object and user entered filename contains "." (for example abc.xyz) and selected extension in filter is ".txt", the filename we get after ShowDialog() call is "abc.xyz" and not "abc.xyz.txt".

This is not the case when **ShowHelp=false**. We get filename as "abc.xyz.txt".

Anyone has idea what should be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you upload a minimal project (to github) for us to debug?

Comment: Project Link: https://github.com/laveshmittal/SaveFileDialog-Error.git @LeiYang

Comment: i can reproduce this problem using the github source. interesting.

Comment: @LeiYang I was able to reproduce the bug in a new project also.

Comment: This also exist in .net framework 2.0. I didn't tried further as I'm expecting that If it exist in both newest and oldest versions together, it was never discovered before and hence not fixed.

Comment: FYI try it with a filename with an extension listed in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT like "abc.pdf" => no change on both